# Can I find GCK-solution with add-form of few functions?

Tags: lattice-crypto

I know that it is hard that find a small $x$ when we know $(A,Ax), Ax=f(x)$ if is GCK on the cyclic lattice.

Then is it hard to find small x_i when we know $(A,X)$ that $$X \leftarrow A_1\cdot x_1 + \cdots + A_n\cdot x_n?$$

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your problem as the initial with other parameters.

The new matrix is $\begin{matrix}A_1,|A_2,|\dots,| A_n\end{matrix}$.

And the new vector is $x_1,| x_2, |\dots,| x_n$.

So, of course it depends of the size of your parameter, but if $n$ is small enough, the hardness of the problem doesn't change.